# Using exec_command to Check if a Windows Directory Exists

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, paramiko, openssh

I'm using Python 2.7 and Paramiko 2.1.2 to check if a Windows directory exists on a server running OpenSSH.  The Windows directory exists on the server, but my code isn't finding it. From my testing, it seems as I'm specifying the directory incorrectly, but I can't figure out why this isn't working.  Although I have not shown it, I don't meet with success if I use "/" instead of "\".  Does anyone have any ideas how to solve the problem, and what may be going on?

Update 1:  This executes properly on the Windows system,

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd /c dir "D:\"')
```

However, I still can't check for the existence of specific directories

Update 2:  This seems to work.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('if [[ -d /cygdrive/d/log ]]; then echo Exists; fi')
```

However, I'm still interested in any explanations as to why following doesn't work, or rather doesn't work consistently.

```
if_exist_path = "cmd /c if exist \"" + log_path + "\" echo Exists"
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(if_exist_path)
```

Consider the code below.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("10.9.8.7", username="FakeUser", password="FakePassword")
log_path = "D:\\Log"
if_exist_path = "cmd /c if exist \"" + log_path + "\" echo Exists"
print("Var 'if_path_exist' is: {}".format(if_exist_path))
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(if_exist_path)
stdoutput = stdout.readlines()
stderror = stderr.readlines()
print("First Stdout is {}".format(stdoutput))
print("First Stderr is {}".format(stderror))
print("")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd /c dir "D:\\Log"')
stdoutput = stdout.read()
stderror = stderr.read()
print("Second Stdout is {}".format(stdoutput))
print("Second Stderr is {}".format(stderror))
print("")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd /c dir "D:\"')
stdoutput = stdout.read()
stderror = stderr.read()
print("Third Stdout is {}".format(stdoutput))
print("Third Stderr is {}".format(stderror))
print("")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd /c dir "D:\\"')
stdoutput = stdout.read()
stderror = stderr.read()
print("Fourth Stdout is {}".format(stdoutput))
print("Fourth Stderr is {}".format(stderror))
print("")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd /c dir "D:\Log"')
stdoutput = stdout.read()
stderror = stderr.read()
print("Fifth Stdout is {}".format(stdoutput))
print("Fifth Stderr is {}".format(stderror))
print("")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cmd /c dir "D:\Log\"')
stdoutput = stdout.read()
stderror = stderr.read()
print("Sixth Stdout is {}".format(stdoutput))
print("Sixth Stderr is {}".format(stderror))
print("")
```

Output:

```
C:\Scripts>SO_Test.py
Var 'if_path_exist' is: cmd /c if exist "D:\Log" echo Exists
First Stdout is []
First Stderr is []

Second Stdout is  Volume in drive D is Apps
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

 Directory of D:\


Second Stderr is File Not Found


Third Stdout is  Volume in drive D is Apps
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

 Directory of D:\

01/26/2017  10:49 PM    <DIR>          Log
01/12/2017  11:34 AM            12,887 Blah.ps1
01/12/2017  01:16 PM            12,082 result.txt
12/12/2016  03:39 PM            23,340 Blahv201.zip
04/15/2017  10:37 PM    <DIR>          Company
01/27/2017  08:19 PM    <DIR>          CompanyBackup
01/12/2017  01:08 PM            10,060 Untitled1.ps1
               4 File(s)         58,369 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  175,276,904,448 bytes free

Third Stderr is

Fourth Stdout is
Fourth Stderr is sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Fifth Stdout is  Volume in drive D is Apps
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

 Directory of D:\


Fifth Stderr is File Not Found

Sixth Stdout is  Volume in drive D is Apps
 Volume Serial Number is xxxx-xxxx

 Directory of D:\


Sixth Stderr is File Not Found
```

Comment: Have you tried running cmd /c dir d:\  instead?  (Please edit the output from that command into your question.)

Comment: Thanks Harry.  I just updated the question.  "D:\" works.  However, "D:\Log\" does not appear to work properly.

Comment: That error you're getting from the fourth test is very suspicious, it implies that `sh` is getting involved somehow and that backslashes and quotes are being processed in multiple layers.  Try the same set of tests, but add in `echo` after each `/c`, e.g., `cmd /c echo dir "D:\Log"`, hopefully you'll be able to see what the command looks like once it has gotten through all the filtering.

Comment: ... but you should also [double-check that the directory name doesn't have any unexpected characters in it](https://superuser.com/q/1199536/96662).

Comment: If the server supports it, you should use SFTP for this rather than plain SSH. Because the server is windows, you might need to sftp into it interactively to figure out the right path to access the D: drive. If the server is Cygwin, I think you'd use "/cygdrive/d/dir" or something along those lines.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I'm completely baffled.  I accidentally reran the test script prior to editing it as you suggested,and I got the expected output..  Coincidentally, I was helping a colleague troubleshoot running commands directly via Plink, and I discovered that I need to use cygdrive commands followed by cmd /c dir.   I think this factors into my problem and solution.   However, my accidental running of the script shows something else is in play.   I'll complete the retests as you suggest later tonight.

Comment: Hi @Kenster -- The server is running OpenSSH, and not a full Cygwin environment.  You are correct though in a Shell environment on a Cygwin type sever, one needs to run Cygdrive commands.  Example:  "/cygdrive/d/log".   As I mentioned to Harry, I was troubleshooting something else last night and hit upon using a command like "cd /cygdrive/d/log && cmd /c dir"  For whatever reason, it didn't seem possible to change paths with native Windows commands (preceded with cmd /c.

Answer (score -2):

You're looking for `os.path.isdir`, or `os.path.exists` 
for directory.

```
if os.path.isdir("/test/to/dir") == True:

    print('dir exists ')

    # you next actions
```

Comment: don't forget to import os

Comment: The OPs code is testing the existence of a directory on a remote machine (via SSH) but this answer only addresses testing the existence of a directory on the local machine.

Comment: @ Mahdi_Bahri   Unless I'm missing something, I don't think that's it.   I'm attempting to check for the existence of a directory on a remote Windows system.  The remote system does not have Python on it.  The local system, from where I'm running the script, has Python, but that doesn't help me.